Additional consent in GTM does not appear to be additional at all, what is wrong?
I have a confusing issue with GTM. I implemented consent mode a few weeks ago but the data team at my work has not seen the expected drop in GA events.
When I look into it I see that "additional" consent doesn't seem to be in addition to built-in.
I have a tag called Update Foo of type Google Analytics: GA4 Event, this comes with built-in consent checks of ad_storage ad_personalization ad_user_data analytics_storage.

If I set additional to either Not set or No additional consent required, run the site in preview mode and set the default consent mode on the site to DENIED for the 4 modes above (verified by the Consent tab in Tag Assistant), Foo still fires.


If I set additional to Require additional consent for tag to fire, specify ad_storage (or any other built-in mode), and run exactly the same test as above, Foo does not fire.

This is not what I would expect, I'd expect additional to mean in addition to.
Is this a flaw in my understanding or a bug in GTM?
